# Let's encryptの証明書の更新が出来ない

Tags: letsencrypt

Let's encryptの証明書の更新すると以下のエラーが表示されます。

```
  Domain: www.exaple.com
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   http://www.exaple.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/VImSUQsPVjhFUuWmj4Rhstrg61XEK8v74nvVMHSx81o
   [45.95.54.195]: "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//IETF//DTD HTML
   2.0//EN\">\n<html><head>\n<title>403
   Forbidden</title>\n</head><body>\n<h1>Forbidden</h1>\n<p"

   Domain: cccc.exaple.com
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   https://cccc.exaple.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/yG2uX4utnascNgeAvv4V3ClE401vDJSsypXV2alZEWM
   [45.7.54.203]: "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//IETF//DTD HTML
   2.0//EN\">\n<html><head>\n<title>403
   Forbidden</title>\n</head><body>\n<h1>Forbidden</h1>\n<p"

   To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address.
```

OS: Ubuntu 18.04

原因はなんでしょうか？
一応ドキュメントルート直下に.well-known/acme-challengeは作成済みです。

以下実行コマンドになります。

```
sudo certbot certonly --dry-run --webroot --webroot-path /var/webroot/public -d www.exaple.com -d cccc.exaple.com -m e@example.co.jp
```

以上宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: 更新のために実行したコマンドや、Webサーバに関する情報なども含まれているとアドバイスが付きやすいと思います。

Comment: `.well-known/acme-challenge`は`certbot`コマンドで自動生成するもののはずなので、`certbot`コマンドの使い方が間違っていると思われます。`certbot`コマンドをどう操作したかも、質問を編集して追加してもらえると何か分かるかもしれません。

Comment: コメント有難うございます。またご連絡が遅れて申し訳ありません。実行コマンドを追記しました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自己解決致しました。
letsencryptではawsのec2 instanceより認証しており、.htaccessにawsからのリクエスト全てブロックしていたのが原因でした。